# Find product by SKU and exclude it

Tags: php, magento

On our site we have some text within a div that shows if the product is in a certain price range (offering finance) within our code.

Now, we want to exclude 1 individual product from showing this box as it's a pre-owned item.

Is there a way of finding a product SKU and then excluding it from the parameters we have?

```
<div class="v12smallwrapper">
<a onclick="showFinance('',<?php echo $_price?>,'<?php echo $_product->getBrand()?>')">
<?php echo $_freeFinance ?>
<?php echo $this->__('Finance available at checkout from <br />£')?>
<?php echo $monthlyPayment2499 ?>
<?php echo $this->__(' a month. ')?>
<?php if ($_price <= 2500):?>
<?php echo $this->__('Buy Now Pay Later finance available')?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $this->__('Click here for details*')?>
</a>
```

I'm not very good with PHP so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php if($_product->getSku() != 'Sku-to-exclude'):
      // code to display the box
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I think the best course of action is to just hide the div. Could I echo out the div with "display:none;" ?

Comment: How would this look in the code I provided? Sorry I'm not very good with PHP @manashvi birla

Comment: yes that is also possible, but this is a simpler approach if you want to exclude only one sku

Answer (score 0):

You can get Product SKU using following way:

```
$productSku = $_product->getSku();
```

And can add condition to statement which you don't want to show on particular product:

```
if($productSku != 'example_product') {
  //Statement   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its not only one product to skip, so:

```
<?php 
  $skuToSkip = array('sku1', 'sku2', 'sku3');
  if(!in_array($_product->getSku(), $skuToSkip)) {
?>
  ...Your box code here...
<?php
  }
?>
```